# Edit message in a specific channel in a specific guild | Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

**Hello**

*(I'm French so sorry for my bad English)*

I want my bot to edit a message in a specific channel, I tried lots of codes but none of them worked.

```
let channels = Bot.guilds.find(g => g.id == "guild id").channels.filter(c => c.id == "another guild id").array();

channels.forEach(channel => {
     channel.fetchMessage("message id").edit("Message Edited");
);
```

I also tried with `for` etc... `channel` is defined, but it can't fetch any message...

---

I don't even know if I can do that...

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) and [`find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) methods to do so as shown below.

```js
// Note: This code must be inside of an async function.

const guild = bot.guilds.get('guildIDhere');
if (!guild) return console.log('Unable to find guild.');

const channel = guild.channels.find(c => c.id === 'channelIDhere' && c.type === 'text');
if (!channel) return console.log('Unable to find channel.');

try {
    const message = await channel.fetchMessage('messageIDhere');
    if (!message) return console.log('Unable to find message.');

    await message.edit('Test.');
    console.log('Done.');
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```